# JMETER MQ Using JSR223 sampler

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0, jsr223, jmeter-4.0

I would like to publish message with different set of data using JMeter jsr223 sampler to MQ Queue. Please can someone help to do this  passing different set of data like product, size, quantity and code. I am able to connect MQ using the JSR223 but not been able to publish. Here is sample message below. Appreciate if any sample groovy or bean

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tstprj="http://my.host.local/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <buy:shopping>
         <product>soaps</product>
         <company>XYZ</company>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         <size>xl</size>
         <code>sop:1234</content>
      </buy:shopping>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot give you neigher "groovy" nor "bean" because we don't know what exact "MQ" you're testing and the instructions and classes will be **very** different depending on the "MQ" broker vendor.

So far I can only suggest to read the following materials:

- [Getting Started with Java Message Service (JMS)](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/intro-java-message-service.html)
- [JMS Step 2 - Using the QueueSend.java Sample Program to Send a Message to a JMS Queue](https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddlewaresupport/post/jms-step-2-using-the-queuesendjava-sample-program-to-send-a-message-to-a-jms-queue)
- [IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial)

Also be informed that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so don't use Beanshell especially for "heavy" operations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am following IBM MQ tutorial from Blazemeter. Do i have to use """ when passing xml message through def payload=String.format(<message")